# Force https if logged in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule in my web.config which is working fine

```
<rule name="RedirectToHttps" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)">
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

The problem now is that I only want to apply this rule to logged in users, is there any way to do this in the web.config? If not what other way could I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible with the IIS URL Rewrite module, as it comes into action before the requests have been authenticated.

You could, however, reserve a subdirectory to your logged users, as for example *~/Members/*, and force the URL Rewrite module to redirect the HTTP requests for this path to the HTTPS equivalent:

```
<rule name="RedirectToHttps" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)">
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/Members/.*" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

Alternatively, you may easily perform the checks manually within your global.asax/Application class:

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the conditions are satisfied

    if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
        uri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;

        // Perform the redirect to the HTTPS equivalent

        Response.Redirect(uri.ToString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one problem, when it does the redirect it is adding :80 to the end of the host i.e. site.local:80/something.aspx I am using this on my local machine. Any suggestions?